# How Hibernate match entity in one-to-one relation, despite of absence of a foreign Key?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am still learning hibernate ORM. I have created 2 entities: student and address.The relation between them is one to one bidirectional.But when I checked the db I found 3 tables :Student,Address and     hibernate_sequence(in which an int attribute called next_val is registered ).

Those are the table structure:
 `student`(`STUDENT_ID`, `FIRST_NAME`, `LAST_NAME`, `SECTION`)
`address`(`ADDRESS_ID`, `CITY`, `COUNTRY`, `STREET`)
`hibernate_sequence`(`next_val`)

I want to know how hibernate match the student to its address despite the absence of a foreign Key.
By the way i tried session.find(Student.class, student3.getId()) and i got the address of that student.

This is my student class :

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "SECTION")
    private String section;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address address;

    public Student() {

    }

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String section) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.section = section;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getSection() {
        return section;
    }

    public void setSection(String section) {
        this.section = section;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName="
                + lastName + ", section=" + section + ", address=" + address
                + "]";
    }

}
```

This is my Address Code :

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;


@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ADDRESS_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign",parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="student"))
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "STREET")
    private String street;

    @Column(name = "CITY")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "COUNTRY")
    private String country;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Student student;

    public Address() {

    }

    public Address(String street, String city, String country) {
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
        this.country = country;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Address [id=" + id + ", street=" + street + ", city=" + city
                + ", country=" + country + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn is the annotation which make this 
so the primary key wil play double role and will act like a foreign key for both tables

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a 1 on 1 relationship, it uses the value of the key of table `student` for the id of the table `address`. You may see these details if you enable logging in `trace` level and (after omitting lots of messages) check the parametererized queries sent to the database and the values for these parameters.